# Any way to get a Restaurant menu from Yelp! API

Tags: api, yelp

Trying to extract some menu data from a restaurant on Yelp using the v2.0 API. The only thing i am getting via the API response is a `menu_provider` field which i don't know how to use - any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Yelp gets their menu information from Locu (and potentially other sources), so they won't share that via their API.

Per their documentation, they provide menu_provider and menu_date_updated, but not actual menu data in their API.

- **Documentation:** http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/business
- **TechCrunch article on partnership:** http://techcrunch.com/2013/04/23/yelp-partners-with-locu-allowing-businesses-to-post-menus-daily-specials-photos-to-yelp-in-real-time/